# Prevent specific fragment within viewpager from refreshing

Tags: android, list, android-viewpager, fragment, adapter

I have several fragments within a viewpager, and the first fragment (TimelineFragment) is being replaced whenever the user chooses to browse a different community.

I'm able to successfully change the TimelineFragment when I changed my FragmentPagerAdapter to FragmentStatePagerAdapter since FragmentPagerAdapter does not update the fragment even when I use pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Hence, I used FragmentStatePagerAdapter with the following code:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

public void setItem(int position, Fragment fragment) {
    fragmentList.set(position, fragment);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
   return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
}
```

The problem is whenever I move to a fragment, that fragment is being refreshed. Which makes my recyclerview within each fragment reload all lists and go to the top of that list.

My goal here is that when the user has chosen to view a different community, the timeline fragment (ALONE, hopefully exluding other fragments) will be the only fragment to reload, and load the respective list based on the chosen community.

Answer (score 0):

the method `onCreateView` in fragment calls each time you move between 3 fragments in view pager. so the solution is:

1- add `static boolean loaded=false;` in your fragment

2- before calling the code that refreshes the recyclerview or any code you don't want to call add

```
    if(!loaded){
    //your code
    ...

    loaded=true;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this just now, but whenever I go back to the fragment it still reloads. Do you think it has something to do with the FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Comment: Can you put your code. And what do you mean by go back to the fragment.  Which fragment?